# Find the largest value of $\delta$ that works for a given choice of $\epsilon$

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x)=4x^2+40x+99$
, $x\in R$
. Since this function is a polynomial we know that it is continuous, so in particular we know that
$$\lim_{x\to−8}f(x)=35=f(−8).$$
That means that for every $\epsilon>0$
we should be able to find a related $\delta>0$
such that

$$|x+8|<\delta⇒|f(x)−35|<\epsilon$$

The goal of this question is to find the largest value of $\delta$
that works for a given choice of $\epsilon$
.

If we choose to take $\epsilon=1/7$
, then what is the largest possible value of $\delta$
?
[Hint: consider for which values of $x$
we have $f(x)=35\pm \epsilon$
.]

I have used the hint and found 4 values of $x$ which gave me 4 inequalities of $\delta$, but they don't help to find the largest value of $\delta$ for the given $\epsilon$. I'm unsure how else to approach the question.

Comment: "they all give me values that δ is *greater* than"?

Comment: @AnneBauval, what i mean by this statement is that im only finding the lower bound of delta

Comment: I understood what you meant but I think you are wrong.

Comment: This makes no sense from the very first!  f(x)= x²+ 40x+ 99 so f(-8)= 64- 320+ 99= 163- 320= -157, NOT 35.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey, Georgie, it appears you have made a blunder in your calculations, you appear to have forgotten the coefficient of x^2, it is 4, NOT 1.

Comment: @AnneBauval can you explain why please

Comment: Can *you* explain *in your post* why you think you are "only finding the lower bound of delta"?

Comment: @AnneBauval because the abs. of x-8 < delta

Comment: The purpose of finding $\delta$ when $\epsilon=\frac{1}{7}$ is to find the value of x farthest from -8 for which $|f(x)-f(-8)|\lt \frac{1}{7}$, thus give you a numerical idea about $\delta(\epsilon=\frac{1}{7})=|x-(-8)|$.

Comment: I hope you are not being taught that this is a good way to do delta-epsilon proofs.

Comment: Please edit your post (not just answer in a comment) to tell what are your "4 inequalities of $δ$" and your reasoning to establish them. particularly why you think they are of the form $δ\ge$ rather than $δ\le.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $h=x+8.$ Then, $f(x)-35=4h(h-6)$ hence

$$|f(x)-35|<\epsilon\iff$$

$$-\frac\epsilon4<h^2-6h<\frac\epsilon4\iff$$

$$\sqrt{9-\frac\epsilon4}<
|h-3|<\sqrt{9+\frac\epsilon4}.$$

When $-\delta<h<\delta,$ $|h-3|$ takes every value in $(3-\delta,3+\delta).$ All these values belong to $\left(\sqrt{9-\frac\epsilon4},\sqrt{9+\frac\epsilon4}\right)$ iff $3-\delta\ge
\sqrt{9-\frac\epsilon4}$ and $3+\delta\le
\sqrt{9+\frac\epsilon4},$ i.e. iff

$$\delta\le\min\left(3-\sqrt{9-\frac\epsilon4},\sqrt{9+\frac\epsilon4}-3\right)=\sqrt{9+\frac\epsilon4}-3.$$

Since we reasoned *by equivalences*, this gives a rigorous and complete proof that for every $\varepsilon>0,$
$$\delta_{max}(\epsilon):=\sqrt{9+\frac\epsilon4}-3$$
is the number you asked for, i.e. the largest $\delta>0$ satisfying
$$|x+8|<\delta⇒|f(x)−35|<\epsilon.$$

$$\delta_{max}(1/7)=\sqrt{9+\frac1{28}}-3\approx\delta:=0.0059.$$
Since we chose $\delta<\delta_\max(1/7),$ we still have
$$|x+8|<\delta⇒|f(x)−35|<\frac17.$$
By definition of $\delta_\max,$ this would of course not hold if we had chosen some $\delta>\delta_\max(1/7),$ like $0.006.$

Comment: Makes no sense to me that you chose an h and found its limits in order to choose a $\delta$ that somehow envelops h and still falls under the same limits. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}|x+8|&\lt \delta\Rightarrow -\delta-8\lt x\lt\delta -8\Rightarrow-4\delta-24\lt 4x+8\lt4\delta-24\lt4\delta+24\\|4x+8|&\lt4\delta+24\\ \underbrace{|f(x)-35|}_{|x+8|\cdot|4x+8|}&\lt4\delta(\delta+6)\lt \epsilon \Rightarrow\delta^2+6\delta-\frac{\epsilon}{4}\lt 0\Rightarrow\delta \lt-3+\frac{\sqrt{36+\epsilon}}
{2}, \delta\gt 0\end{align}$$

Check:

$$|f(x)-35|=|x+8|\cdot|4x+8|\lt \underbrace{\delta}_{\frac{\sqrt{36+\epsilon}-6}{2}}\cdot \underbrace{(4\delta+24)}_{4\left (\frac{\sqrt{36+\epsilon}-6}{2}+6\right)}\lt \epsilon$$

Therefore, $\delta_{\text{max}}(\epsilon)=-3+\frac{\sqrt{36+\epsilon}}{2}$

$\epsilon=\frac{1}{7}\Rightarrow \delta_{\text{max}}(\frac{1}{7})=\frac{\sqrt{36+\frac{1}{7}}}{2}-3$